# Android - Shared Element Transition In Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, transition, element, shared

I wanted to know if there is any way to use shared elements between an activity/fragment and a dialog?

I have a project which contains dialogs and I want to make a transition between an ImageView in Activity's view hierarchy to the relevant ImageView in my GalleryDialog.

I searched a bit and found this link:

[Shared element transition with Dialog Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507907/shared-element-transition-with-dialog-activity)

which describes the workflow for using dialog themed activity. I was wondering if I could do it without using an extra activity and passing data with intent to that activity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIK its impossible to use shared elements between a fragment/activity and a dialog.
The best way implement this is the link you mentioned, using a dialog-themed activity that looks like a dialog and send data via intent to the acctivity.

For sending large data with intent, you can either use parcelables or an external place to store data, e.g. a singleton class or a database.
Have a look at the following answer regarding transferring large data between activities:

[Android - What's the best way to share data between activities?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4878259/5551354)

Comment: I finally decided to leave it. btw since dialogfragments are a type of fragment, there might be a way to use transition between dialogfragment and fragment.

Comment: @SinaRezaei Did you found a way to achieve transitions in dialogs?