# Android Show Dialog Fragment from SharedElement of Activities

Tags: android, android-activity, translation, dialogfragment

I want to show a Dialogfragment that appear from a SharedElement of my Activity. I tried SharedElementTransition and that not working. Here is the code:

```
FragmentManager fm = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
AddHistoryFragment mAddHistoryFragment = new AddHistoryFragment();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    mAddHistoryFragment.setSharedElementReturnTransition(TransitionInflater.from(
                        this).inflateTransition(R.transition.change_image_trans));
    mAddHistoryFragment.setExitTransition(TransitionInflater.from(
                        this).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.fade));

    mAddHistoryFragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(
                        this).inflateTransition(R.transition.change_image_trans));
    mAddHistoryFragment.setEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(
                        this).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.fade));
   fm.beginTransaction().add(mAddHistoryFragment,"add History")
                        .addSharedElement(ivAddExpense, ivAddExpense.getTransitionName()).commit();
   }else {
        mAddHistoryFragment.show(fm, "History");
   }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly it won't work. Shared element transitions only work with `replace` fragment transaction, but `DialogFragment.show()` uses `add` transaction.

Also, see this question, maybe its solution will work for you
[Android - Shared Element Transition In Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33596296/android-shared-element-transition-in-dialog)