# Make shared element transition betweeen fragment and dialog

Tags: java, android, dialog, kotlin, fragment

I make an android app which is build with only one activity. I don't want to use activities. Everything is a fragment or something. For FullScreenDialogs, according to material design I have made a dialog with a full screen theme.

Now I want to make animations like sharedElementTransition from the fragments view to the dialogs view.

The dialog just calls `setContentView(...)` to initialize the layout.

In the fragment i call `MyFullScreenDialog(ctx).show()`

Does someone know, how to implement this feature? It would be very nice if there is a clear and easy solution.

Thanks for help!

EDIT: I don't want to use activities!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Shared Element Transition In Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33596296/android-shared-element-transition-in-dialog)

Comment: No, he said how to use it with an DialogActivity. I don't want to use an activity.