# Activity to fragment shared element transition?

Tags: android, material-design, android-animation

I have seen a lot of examples of `Activity` To `Activity` or `Fragment` to `Fragment` shared element transitions on the internet.

However not one `Activity` to `Fragment` one. Neither do the android docs encourage/discourage or talk about such a scenario . I am also astonished as to why wasn't the need for this felt by other developers.

Is it not possible ? . Can't we share an element between an Activity A and a fragment inside it ? .

A common scenario is like I have a list of students on an Activity and upon clicking them I see a fragment with their details.

Comment: **A common scenario is like I have a list of students on an Activity and upon clicking them I see a fragment with their details.** how will you do that ?? can you specify ?

Comment: you are saying the fragment is in the activity itself..so are you going to play with visiblity on clicking each item??

Comment: @SantanuSur I would commit and uncommit the fragment when the row is clicked .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507907/shared-element-transition-with-dialog-activity/28508306#28508306 you can try this..atleast the activity will be visible... or you have to hard code the animation... in the same activity