# Why shared element transition make transparent Activity blank?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-styles, android-transitions

I have a MainActivity containing a Fragment, the Fragment has a FAB button and clicklistener star a new Transparent Activity.
Transition works wellwith pairing views, but the Transparent Activity turns blank when I use ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult.

What's wrong?

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {

                ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
                        makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity, (View) fab, fab.getTransitionName());
                ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(activity, intent, REQUEST, options.toBundle());
            }else{
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST);
            }
```

My Style res/values

```
<style name="AppTheme.BaseTranslucentParent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/RobotoTextViewStyle</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/RobotoEditTextStyle</item>
        <item name="buttonStyle">@style/RobotoButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

My style res/values-v21

```
<style name="AppTheme.BaseTranslucent" parent="AppTheme.BaseTranslucentParent">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitTransition">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Do you have any news on this ? Did you find any solution ?

Comment: Sorry, Not yet, I did'nt find any solution. Let me know if you find it please. Thanks

Comment: @ilansas Refer this question :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507907/shared-element-transition-with-dialog-activity

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542517/activity-with-transparent-background/39403147#39403147 May be help u.